# Meta for developers - Verification code too short

Tags: facebook, registration, verification

I'm busy going through the process of **registering** as a **developer** on **Meta** to try build out a **service** application but on the **verification** screen I'm receiving an SMS that is 5 digits long and the **submit** button is **disabled** unless there are at least 6 characters typed in. Is this a known issue from Meta's side or how can I request a new **verification** code?

Comment: to stackoverflow -> this is the very first response we get in google.... we're just trying to fix it